# ssh'ing via a proxy, but connect is not found

Tags: linux, apt

I installed debian from a business card cd iso (basically a very stripped down version of it).

I am trying to ssh to a machine via a proxy (set up in my .ssh/config), but am receiving an error:

```
ssh user@servername.com -v
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze2, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for servername.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec connect -S proxy-im.proxyhost.com:1080 servername.com 22
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: connect: not found
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

It seems I don't have a command called "connect" installed on my machine. This is the manpage of the command:
http://perkamon.alioth.debian.org/online/man2/connect.2.php

apt-get install connect fails. Is it part of some other package? If so how do I find it?

Answer (score 2):

I just did a search for "apt-get install connect" in a popular search engine, and it autocompleted to "apt-get install connect-proxy"

I still would have like to have seen a way to know what package this command was in via the man page, otherwise how would someone track something like this down.

Comment: On Ubuntu you could just have typed `connect` on the command line, and it would automatically tell you what the package name is. Usually the package name will be the same on Debian. There might be a way to enable the same feature on Debian such that typing a command which isn't installed will automatically tell you which package you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually find out which package to install in order to get a specific command is by using the `command-not-found` package. That can be installed by typing:

```
apt-get install command-not-found
```

After installing `command-not-found` and restarting `bash` I can simply type `connect` to find the name of the package needed:

```
$ connect
The program 'connect' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install connect-proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you found wrong config file or tutorial.
Try to use nc(nectat) with ProxyCommand:

> ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -X connect -x 192.0.2.0:8080 %h %p

or from shell

> ssh -v  -i ~/.ssh/my_Favorite_key.pem -o ProxyCommand='nc -x
>   jumphost:30022  %h %p'user@dst_host_name

in newer ssh version (since 7.3) you can use ProxyJump
see ssh_config man page for details.
another one good tutorial is
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts

Answer (score -1):

Here you find the solution

`ssh USER@FINAL_DEST -o "ProxyCommand=nc -X connect -x PROXYHOST:PROXYPORT %h` %p"